# No llama a la funcion

Tags: php, javascript

Intendo hacer un eliminacion de registros de una tabla con php y javascript, pero al momento de llamar a la funcion que hace el Delete, no hace nada .

Con este codigo llamo a la funcion

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["delete-contrato-select"])) { 
       $idContratoSelect = $_POST['id_tipo_contratoDelete'];
       $CbContratoController -> delete($idContratoSelect);
  }
?>
```

Esta es mi funcion donde esta el Delete

```
<?php

 class CbContratoController {

   function delete($id_tipo_contrato){ 
      require_once ('conex/conex.php'); 
      $sqlDelete="DELETE FROM tipo_contrato WHERE id_tipo_contrato = '".$id_tipo_contrato."'";  
      $res = $conex->query($sqlDelete);
   }

 }

?>
```

Y aqui obtengo el id del registro

```
 function deleteCbContrato(id_tipo_contrato){     
  document.formDeleteContrato.id_tipo_contratoDelete.value = id_tipo_contrato;                

  $('#myModalDelete').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#myInput').focus()
  });


}
```

Boton de Eliminar

```
 <button id="delete-contrato-modal" name="delete-contrato-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-danger btn-just-icon remove" onclick="deleteCbContrato('<?php echo($row_herramientas['id_tipo_contrato']); ?>');"><i class="material-icons" data-target="#myModalDelete" data-toggle="modal" >close</i></button>
```

Codigo del modal donde obtengo el id_tipo _contrato

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModalDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalDeleteLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalDeleteLabel">Eliminación de Registro</h4>
                    </div>

                    <form role="form" name="formDeleteContrato" method="post" action="contratos.php">
                        <div class="modal-body">                                    
                                <div class="input-group">
                                <label for="id_tipo_contrato">¿Desea eliminar el registro seleccionado?</label>
                                </div>       
                                <div class="input-group">
                                 <label for="id_tipo_contrato">Registro: </label>
                                 <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="id_tipo_contratoDelete" name="id_tipo_contratoDelete" >                                        
                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button id="delete-contrato-select" name="delete-contrato-select" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>                                        
                                <button id="cancel"type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>   
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: ¿Qué fallo te da?

Comment: @Csc99  Simplemente no hace el delete

Comment: Como mandas la informacion?

Comment: Para usar un método de una clase previamente debes crear un objeto de la misma.

Comment: @HectorLopez mm... no se si me puedan instruir, soy nuevo programando y no entiendo muy bien la logica todavia

Answer (score 0):

Pongamos que tienes una clase App dentro del archivo `"App.php"`;

```
class App
{

public function hello(){
    echo "hello word";
}

}
```

Para llamar a ese metodo desde otro sitio tienes que crear un objeto de la clase App;

```
require("App.php");  //Indicas que vas autilizar ese archivo

$app = new App();  //guardas en $app una instancia de la clase App

$app->hello(); //eso deberia ejecutar el metodo hola mundo!
```

Espero que con este ejemplo te hagas una pequeña idea para tu problema.

Comment: Para crear el objeto puede ser en el mismo lugar donde mando lllamar a la funcion?

Comment: Si, de hecho ha de ser así, vas a llamar a la función desde el objeto como te he ejemplificado en `$app->hello()`.

Answer (score 0):

Si no vas a instanciar la clase "CbContratoController" desde donde llamas el método delete, entonces debes hacer que dicho método ("delete") dentro de la clase sea estático, así:

```
<?php

class CbContratoController {

  public static function delete($id_tipo_contrato){
    ...
  }
}
```

Y lo llamarias así:

```
<?php

require_once('CbContratoController.php');

if (isset($_POST["delete-contrato-select"])) { 
  $idContratoSelect = $_POST['id_tipo_contratoDelete'] ;
  CbContratoController::delete($idContratoSelect); 
}
```

---

Pero la mejor practica seria hacer una instancia de "CbContratoController", así:

```
<?php

require_once('CbContratoController.php');

if (isset($_POST["delete-contrato-select"])) { 
  $idContratoSelect = $_POST['id_tipo_contratoDelete'];
  $contratoCtrl = new CbContratoController();
  $contratoCtrl->delete($idContratoSelect); 
}
```

Y tu método delete ya no debería ser estático:

```
<?php

class CbContratoController {

  public function delete($id_tipo_contrato){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Lo hice asi como me recomiendas, pero sigue sin hacer la elminacion del registro :/

Comment: Verifica el string "$sqlDelete" del metodo delete, si el query concatenado en esta variable esta correcto, verifica tambien que la columna "id_tipo_contrato" en la base de datos sea string, ya que en tu query la concatenas con comillas simple; si la columna es de tipo númerico, debes quitarle esas comillas simples.

Comment: La variable si esta corrrecta, en mi base de datos manejo el id como tipo VARCHAR

Comment: conex.php es una clase? porque si es así, tambien la debes instanciar; en tu codigo no la instancia, solo llamas al metodo query $res = $conex->query($sqlDelete); ... es decir que deberia hacer esto antes $conex = new Conex(); ó new ComoSeLlameLaClase()

Comment: Es la conexión a mi base de datos

Comment: Si, pero verifica si la funcion $conex->query() es un metodo de una clase o una funcion estática.

Comment: Este es el codigo `$conex = new mysqli($hostname_conex ,$username_conex , $password_conex,$database_conex );
if ($conex === false){
 die("ERROR: No se estableció la conexión. ". mysqli_connect_error());
} `

Comment: Ok, y la conexión a la DB esta bien? ... no te sale algún error cuando ejecutas el codigo?

Comment: No ningun error, porque extraigo los datos bien para mostrarlos en un modal, puedo hacer inserciones y actualizar los registros, solo me esta dando problemas el de eliminar

Comment: Cuando haces el submit del formulario, que valor tiene ó imprime la variable $sqlDelete ?

Comment: Edite la pregunta, ahi añadi lo demas del codigo

Comment: Aparentemente todo luce correcto, pero insisto debes verificar que valor tiene la variable $sqlDelete despues de ejecutada esta linea: $sqlDelete="DELETE FROM tipo_contrato WHERE id_tipo_contrato = '".$id_tipo_contrato."'";

Comment: Es que con el modal  me muestra en la pagina el id del contrato para verificar si se desea eliminar, osea que si lo obtiene el id pero lo que no hace es la funcion :/